# Spring Integration: Mapping - a default branch

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I've got a transaction flow:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow eventProcessingFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(
                Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(mqConnectionFactory)

                        .destination("queue/transaction-event"))
                .split()
                .<AppEvent, String>route(event -> event.getType(),
                        mapping -> mapping
                                .subFlowMapping("ORDER", subflow -> ...)
                                .subFlowMapping("PERSON", subflow -> ...))
                                .???when_others"(subflow -> ...))
                )

                .handle(m -> System.out.println(m.getPayload()))
                .get();
    }
```

I process events of different types. A message of each type is handled a special way. I've got to expect I could face an event of unknown or not-yet-known type. I need to configure the mapping the way an event which type I didn't recognize, is handled by a subflow or ignored at all.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Add `.defaultOutputChannel("unknown.input")` and add

```java
@Bean
IntegrationFlow unknown() {
    return f -> f.handle(...);
}
```

`mapping` is probably not the best choice for the variable name, something like `router` might be better.

```java
@Bean
IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return f -> f.<String, String>route(p -> p, router -> router
            .subFlowMapping("foo", sf -> sf.log())
            .subFlowMapping("bar", sf -> sf.log())
            .defaultOutputChannel("unknown.input"));
}
```